# Is there a way to debug softirq?

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, softirq

my purpose :

log **debug info(ratio , address, else)of softirq** generation in specific situation.
any information can be helpful.

I suppose some suspicious device driver but has no clue which generated heavy load.

I'll thanks for any recommend like "read this manual".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to debug softirq?

Probably yes, since the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) is open source. Actually, it is even [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

So you could download its source code (at end of 2020, Linux 5.10), and study it, and improve it.

You might read more about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (including [bpf(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html) & [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) & [socket(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html)) then use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [dmesg(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) or [perf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) or [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html). See also [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) with [netlink(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) and [libnetlink(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libnetlink.3.html)

You technically could write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to compile your Linux kernel, so that your GCC compiler automatically improves your Linux kernel (e.g. by automatically "adding" appropriate instrumentation code).

You might also write your [Linux kernel module](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/index.html#).

In a few months (perhaps February 2021) you might use [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) for such a purpose (static analysis of the source code of your kernel, or module). Consider also using [Frama-C](https://www.frama-c.com/) or [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and afraid of [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

For the kernel side, ask also on [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/).

My recommendation would be to minimize kernel changes, and if possible and permitted, code more application code (maybe related to [systemd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd.1.html), which I don't understand much) and less kernel code.

Comment: It’s strange you haven’t mentioned `perf` which is the tool #1 for such area of interest.

Comment: Thanks. Improved my answer

Comment: Thanks for all you guy's kindness... since I was searching for 'system profiling feature' (and didn't know how to call this topic). 
perf is the best answer for me. but still I have problem that my kernel version is too low(2.4.x, and perf is available 2.6.+).

Comment: but I can try 'perf' because I have same type of machine that have appropriate kernel version, have same problem with system I mentioned. after that I'll debug device driver directly, using method first recommended. Thanks!

Comment: Ask permission to update your Linux kernel. The current version is 5.10 (at end of 2020)